# Symfony2 how to integrate FOSUserBundle register form inside template

Tags: symfony, twig

i try to integrate the FOSUserBundle register form into my homepage (index.html.twig template. In my index.html.twig, i use the render function to show the form in my login block as follow :

```
{% block container %}
[...]
    {% block login %}
        {% render url('fos_user_registration_register') %}      
    {% endblock login %}
[...]
{% endblock container %}
```

All is ok at this point.But when i submit the form, with errors, the FOSUserBundle controler redirect to my overrided register template, and only the form is rendered, not all the page with the form inside. I tried to extend the overided register form to write into the login block

```
{% extends "ELSiteBundle:Site:index.html.twig" %}

{% block login %}
<div>
<form ...>
    [my html form]
</form>
</div>
{% endblock login %}
```

It works when FOSUserBundle redirect to the register template, but now, when the homepage is called, i get a duplicate html content into the login block (it rewrites the whole page into login block).

So my question : How can i render the register.html.twig template into my login block, for both form (default, and with error) ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the Resources/views/layout.html.twig template:

```
{% extends 'AcmeDemoBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Acme Demo Application{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

[Overriding Default FOSUserBundle Templates](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md)

Then if you using `{{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register')) }}`

when errors occur you will be on register page with your common layout style.

If you using `{% render url('fos_user_registration_register') %}`

you can override Register controller, then trigger form submission with isSubmitted() and depend of that load template with or without `{% extends "ELSiteBundle:Site:index.html.twig" %}` part.

Comment: My login block isn't in my layout template but in my index.html.twig template. I only need to show the register form on the homepage.

Comment: Are you try with: 

{{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register')) }}

If you using {% render url('fos_user_registration_register') %} you need to change the route of the form and probably override the form type.

Comment: Yes, but when errors occur, i'm redirected on /register and i lose my template style